# In android carousel view, How can I launch multiple activities when click on android carousel view images?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

My question is, How can I launch multiple activities when click on android carousel view images?

I have tried to write some piece of code that is given below.  But it's launch only one activity instead of multiple one by one, So kindly check this...

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
public static Fragment newInstance(MainActivity context, int pos, float scale, boolean isBlured) {
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putInt("pos", pos);
  b.putFloat("scale", scale);

  return Fragment.instantiate(context, MyFragment.class.getName(), b);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 /* if (container == null) {
    return null;
  }*/

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(400,400);
  LinearLayout fragmentLL  = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mf, container, false);
  int pos   = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
  TextView tv  = (TextView) fragmentLL.findViewById(R.id.text);

  tv.setText("Image " + pos);

  ImageView iv = (ImageView) fragmentLL.findViewById(R.id.pagerImg);

  iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  iv.setImageResource(MainActivity.mainActivityCtx.coverUrl[pos]);
  iv.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
  iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        /*Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),image1.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/
        int postion=0;
        switch (postion)
        {
          case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(getActivity(), image1.class);
            startActivity(newActivity0);
            break;
          case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getActivity(), image2.class);
            startActivity(newActivity1);
            break;
          case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(getActivity(), image3.class);
            startActivity(newActivity2);
            break;
          case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(getActivity(), image4.class);
            startActivity(newActivity3);
            break;
          case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(getActivity(), image5.class);
            startActivity(newActivity4);
            break;
        }
    }
  });


  // MyLinearLayout root = (MyLinearLayout) fragmentLL.findViewById(R.id.root);
  //float scale   = this.getArguments().getFloat("scale");
  //root.setScaleBoth(scale);

  return fragmentLL;
}
}
```

R.id.pagerImage is the id of LinearLayout image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `final` at `int pos`

```
final int pos   = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
```

change variable of `switch` statement, `position` to `pos`

```
switch (pos) {
```

Comment: i did it but it's given me cannot resolve method getArguments().

Comment: do you start frament with 'fragment.newInstance' method?